# Getting an error saying to check for the object to exist with a excel destination

Tags: ssis, bids

> error at data flow tax excel destination open a rowset for $SHEET234
>   failed. Check that the object exists in the database

I'm getting the above error when trying to export data from sql server to an excel file.

Why is it giving me an error saying, which I am assuming is because the file doesnt' exist?  But the whole point of an excel destination is to create the file for me no?

Comment: I dont do a lot with Excel in SSIS but the default sheet that is created when a new Excel file is created is Sheet1 and you would refrence that $Sheet1, if your code is trying to refrence a sheet titled SHEET234, that may be the issue because it does not exist

Comment: Does this occur when building the SSIS or during run time?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a space in your Excel file name? If so, try removing the space and testing it in a new Data Flow Task and see if that helps. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Similar to DEEPAK LAKHOTIA, after renaming the worksheets (right-click on the tabs) and removing the white spaces and decimals, the problem disappeared and the data loaded.

[image]